# Are prisons the main lobby behind police?

Tags: united-states

Prison labor existed long before police in common law countries. As far as I can see, police dont really have any lobbying behind them besides the police themselves and also the for profit prison lobby.

Is there any other significant lobby supporting police besides the prison lobby?

Comment: usually I think of a "lobby" as groups that advocate for certain laws. So I don't follow your question - there's no one lobbying for the existence of police (since they exist). Are you asking about who is lobbying to give police *more* powers or *more* guns? or something like that

Comment: Yeah, this is a strange question. The main "lobby" for police is the public who finds them important to enforce the laws.

Comment: If a for-profit prison interest wanted to insure revenue, they'd attack it via making sure that laws were on the book with harsh mandatory incarceration requirements (mandatory sentences for marijuana possession, or "three strikes" laws that can send someone away for a lengthy time for a petty offense, would be examples). There would be no reason to try and directly fund, maintain or support the police, as their normal function is to up hold and enforce the laws on the books.

Comment: @divibisan - I don't think it's that odd of a question.  You hear this kind of conspiracy "connecting the dots" on the liberal end of the foil-hat brigade, when they are trying to cast a wide net on all aspects of the criminal justice system.

Comment: That is not how politics works. Dispersed mass interest loses to concentrated special interest. Therefore lobbying.

Answer (score 7):

**TLDR:**

80% or so of all US residents want the same or even more police presence.

That's a significant "lobby" supporting police in the US.

**Full answer:**

Per a recent [Gallup poll](https://news.gallup.com/poll/316571/black-americans-police-retain-local-presence.aspx?utm_source=tagrss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=syndication):

> **Black Americans Want Police to Retain Local Presence**
>
> Story Highlights
>
> - Black Americans a bit more likely than most other groups to see police locally
> - Still, most (81%) want police to spend same amount of or more time in their area
> - Big racial gaps seen in views of police fairness, perceived bias
>
> WASHINGTON, D.C. -- When asked whether they want the police to spend more time, the same amount of time or less time than they currently do in their area, most Black Americans -- 61% -- want the police presence to remain the same. This is similar to the 67% of all U.S. adults preferring the status quo, including 71% of White Americans.
>
> Meanwhile, nearly equal proportions of Black Americans say they would like the police to spend more time in their area (20%) as say they'd like them to spend less time there (19%).
>
> ...
>
> **Bottom Line**
>
> It's not so much the volume of interactions Black Americans have with the police that troubles them or differentiates them from other racial groups, but rather the quality of those interactions.
>
> Most Black Americans want the police to spend at least as much time in their area as they currently do, indicating that they value the need for the service that police provide. However, that exposure comes with more trepidation for Black than White or Hispanic Americans about what they might experience in a police encounter. And those harboring the least confidence that they will be treated well, or who have had negative encounters in the past, are much more likely to want the police presence curtailed.
>
> ...

Comment: But are there any actual lobby

Comment: @JognBelvin 80% of the voting population of the United States is quite a lobby.  If you have the impression that the US populace in general - across all races - does not support the local police forces, you need to get a better source for your news.  "Defund the police" is only supported by about 1 in 5 voters.  There might be quite a bit of uneasiness about specific police practices that call for some serious reforms of both police forces and their practices, but that's far short of eliminating them altogether.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please remember that this is not a debate website. Use comments to discuss how the answer could be improved. Do not use comments to engage in debates with other users. For more information on how comments should and should not be used on this website, please refer to [the help article about the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).